# Finding the derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given that $pV = 3600$, find the value of $\frac{dp}{dV}$ when $p=40$. I don't understand why the answer is $-\frac{4}{9}$. Can someone explain that?

Comment: or do you mean $$\frac{dV}{dp}$$?

Comment: No, I mean $\frac{dp}{dV}$

Comment: Surely this can't be right, these variables are inversely proportional to each other so the derivative should be negative.

Comment: Oh sry, it should be -90

Comment: I think ,it should be $\frac{-4}{9}$.

Comment: It should be $-40/90$ I suppose.

Comment: @SydneySniper Is now the given answer $-\frac{4}{9}$ ? Why you had posted $-90$ ?

Comment: Sorry there was an error I went and cross checked and asked my teacher. He said it should be $-\frac{4}{9}$

Answer (score 4):

$pV=3600$, so $V=\frac{3600}{p}$. Then 
$$\frac{dp}{dV}\cdot V + p\cdot \frac{dV}{dV}=0$$
$$\frac{dp}{dV}\cdot V = -p$$
$$\frac{dp}{dV} = -\frac{p}{V}=-\frac{40}{\frac{3600}{40}}=-\frac{4}{9}$$

Answer (score 3):

For $p=40$ we have $V=\dfrac{3600}{40}=90$. Since $p=\dfrac{3600}{V}=3600V^{-1}$, it follows that
$$
\dfrac{dp}{dV}=-\dfrac{3600}{V^2}=-\dfrac{3600}{90^2}=-\dfrac49.
$$

Answer (score 2):

By product rule

$$pV=3600\implies V\dfrac{dp}{dV}+p=0\implies\frac{dp}{dV}=-\frac pV$$

The answer should be $\displaystyle-\frac49$.

Answer (score 1):

$p=\frac{3600}{V} \Rightarrow \frac{dp}{dV}= \frac{-3600}{V^2}$. Now when $p=40, V= 90$ so you should get $ \frac{dp}{dV}=\frac{-3600}{90^2}=\frac{-4}{9}$

Answer (score 1):

Here $PV=3600$,then $P=\frac{3600}V$.Now $\frac{dP}{dV}=\frac{-3600}{V^2}$ but at $P=40,V=90.$So $\frac{dP}{dV}=\frac{-3600}{90^2}=\frac{-3600}{8100}=\frac{-4}{9}$